# Searching multiple tables for single login credential

Tags: php, sql, apache, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Relatively new to PHP and **extremely** rusty on my SQL

Spit an existing table: `users` into two tables `student` and `professor` for different types of users, but now having issues with logins failing. The tables are almost exactly the same except for the primary keys (`studentID` and `professorID`) so they both contain `uName` and `email` columns

the original statement used (when previously searching one table):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uName=? OR email=?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit(); }
```

now attempting to use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student, professor WHERE uName=? OR email=?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit(); }
```

`mysqli_stmt_prepare()` fails every time and returns the above "sqlerror" header, but i don't understand the problem?

the search works fine when using either table alone but not when searching both, looking for explanation with the answer.

Also...
the tables are not directly connected, but an `account` table does relate them if that helps to make a working `SELECT` statement

```
-account-         -student-          -professor-
accountID pk      studentID pk       professorID pk
studentID fk      uName              uName
professorID fk    email              email
                  password           password
```

Comment: You can use single table with user roles

Comment: why didn't you use `joins`?

Comment: please elaborate